# Is there a better term for a "dumbphone"?

Tags: synonyms

Phones that only let you make phone calls and send and receive messages are often called "dumbphones". This is in contrast to Internet-enabled phones with advanced capabilities running operating systems like Android and iOS, those are called "smartphones".

I personally don't like using the term "dumb" to mean unintelligent or idiotic, and I make an effort to avoid using it that way. Similarly, I would like to find a better term then "dumbphone".

Comment: ***Feature Phones***:    a mobile phone that incorporates features such as the ability to access the Internet and store and play music but lacks the advanced functionality of a smartphone. (https://www.google.com/search?q=feature+phone+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use a term such as "basic phone" or "non-smartphone".

However these days "dumbphone" has become the accepted terminology when referring to these devices, and is not meant to be derogatory - so you should not feel bad about using this term.